# How to get right side position of element?

Tags: javascript, css

I have div on the page and I need to know what is its position from the right relevant to the viewport. I have tried this code:

```
const el = this.searchWrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
el.right
```

but this is not what I need because getBoundingClientRect() starts calculation from the left side but I need calculate what is the distance between element and right side of the viewport like on the screen below
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const span = document.querySelector('span');

const rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();

const position = window.innerWidth - rect.right + div.offsetWidth;

span.style.left = position + 'px';

console.log(position);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div>I am a div</div>
<span>Distance from left</span>
```

Minus the right `rect` of the element from the width of the window, then add the width of the div to find the position.

If you just needed the distance from the right side of the viewport, minus `position` from `window.innerWidth`:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const span = document.querySelector('span');

const rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();

const position = window.innerWidth - rect.right + div.offsetWidth;

span.style.right = window.innerWidth - position + 'px';

console.log(window.innerWidth - position);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>I am a div</div>
<span>Distance from right</span>
```

**EDIT**

From right side of the window to the element's start:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const span = document.querySelector('span');

const rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();

const position = window.innerWidth - rect.right;

span.style.right = window.innerWidth - position + 'px';

console.log(window.innerWidth - position);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>I am a div</div>
<span>Distance from the right-side of the window to the left-side of the div</span>
```

Comment: sorry for the late response. It is not working corretly for some reason. I have incorrect calculations. And why you used span here? I need value in px from the right side of window till element start

Comment: The span is just to demonstrate the distance. Edited my answer

Comment: To what extent is this cross-platform?  Apparently, getBoundingClientRect() will return incorrect answers with Safari on iOS, according to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Not sure @IronPillow. Looks like an issue with zooming on Safari iOS